# Error creating an Application Pool in IIS programmatically with an installer

Tags: c#, iis, windows-installer

I have created an Setup project with Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.1.

I have this post install custom action:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class PostInstallActions : Installer
{
    private const string siteName = "Default Web Site";
    private const string appPoolName = "TRZF AppPool";
    private const string webAppPath = "/TRZF";
    private const string windowsAuthenticationPath =
        "system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication";

    public PostInstallActions()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public override void Install(IDictionary state)
    {
        base.Install(state);
        // Do my custom install actions
    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary state)
    {
        base.Commit(state);

        // Do my custom commit actions
        ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

        ApplicationPool trzfAppPool =
            serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(appPoolName);
        trzfAppPool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
        trzfAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "v4.0";
        trzfAppPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType =
            ProcessModelIdentityType.ApplicationPoolIdentity;

        Application trzfApp = serverManager.Sites[siteName].Applications[webAppPath];
        trzfApp.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;

        Configuration config = trzfApp.GetWebConfiguration();
        ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = 
            config.GetSection(windowsAuthenticationPath);

        windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true;

        serverManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

And I get an error running the installer on a Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB, version 1607.

The error is on Commit phase:

> Error 1001. Error 1001. An exception occurred during the Commit phase
>   of the installation. This exception will be ignored and installation
>   will continue. However, the application might not function correctly
>   after installation is complete. --> This configuration section cannot
>   be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a
>   parent level. Locking is either by default
>   (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with
>   overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

I have ran it with administrative rights, but I get the same error.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows authentication section is by default locked so you cannot set it in `web.config` (what you attempted in the code above). Try to set it in `applicationHost.config` as a `location` tag, as belows

```
            // server config "Website1"
            var config = server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            // enable Windows authentication
            var windowsSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", "WebSite1");
            Assert.Equal(OverrideMode.Inherit, windowsSection.OverrideMode);
            Assert.Equal(OverrideMode.Deny, windowsSection.OverrideModeEffective);
            Assert.False(windowsSection.IsLocked);
            Assert.True(windowsSection.IsLocallyStored);

            var windowsEnabled = (bool)windowsSection["enabled"];
            Assert.True(windowsEnabled);
            windowsSection["enabled"] = false;
            Assert.Equal(false, windowsSection["enabled"]);
```